# This looks like spam notice

Tags: support

I've written a long question, which included own research and my own conclusions so far.

When posting, the site gives me an error: "This looks like spam". No description of why it looks like spam.

So what makes the system decide something looks like spam? Did I put something wrong in the question? Is it too long? (5463 chars).

It only contains 2 links, both to stack exchange network sites.

Comment: If you could post the question somewhere else, like pastebin, and link it, perhaps someone will be able to suggest improvements. (Usually I'd recommend you to post it in your meta question here, but I guess would run afoul of the very same spam filter...)

Answer (score 1):

The spam detection algorithms look for a lot of common signs of spam, and no, SE is not going to give us the details, as I'm sure spammers would misuse them.

Think about the text, repeated words, keywords that spammers commonly use, phrasing, and a million other things.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to allow for the post, with an automatic flag for moderator review?

Comment: @Tim No because then we'd never see another legitimate question again and it'd be the end of SE as we know it

Comment: SE may not give us the details, but various people have analyzed the site's behavior and have released detailed information about how various systems like the spam system and vote fraud detection algorithm work.